# Google Analytics Python API was Pulling More than 10k rows, but now it doesn't

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

So the issue I'm running into right now is that I wrote some code to pull records from Google Analytics and was successfully pulling 76k rows worth of data. Then I came back the next day, no code was changed, and now I can only pull 10k rows of data. Anyone have any idea why this would be the case?

Below is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Sep  2 10:52:32 2022

@author: McCormickT
"""
import sys, importlib, pandas as pd
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import time, datetime as dt

#%%
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
    KEY_FILE = 'KEY_FILE.json'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE, SCOPES)
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting','v4', credentials=credentials)

    return analytics

#====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|
#Get One Report Page
def get_report(analytics, pagetoken):
    VIEW_ID = '12345678'
    DIMENSIONS = ['ga:clientId', 'ga:adContent']
    METRICS = ['ga:sessions',
              'ga:pageviews',
              'ga:totalEvents',
              'ga:goal1Completions',
              'ga:goalCompletionsAll',
              'ga:sessionDuration']
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId' : VIEW_ID,
                    'dateRanges' : [{'startDate' : '2022-09-27', 'endDate' : 'yesterday'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression':i} for i in METRICS],
                    'dimensions': [{'name':j} for j in DIMENSIONS],
                    'pageSize' : 100000,
                    'pageToken' : pagetoken
                    }],
                }
        ).execute()
#====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|
def ga_to_df(analytics,pagetoken,rows):

    response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)

    #Reader, Dimension Headers, Metric Headers
    columnHeader = response.get("reports")[0].get('columnHeader' , {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions' , [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader' , {}).get('metricHeaderEntries' , [])

    #Pagination
    pagetoken = response.get("reports")[0].get('nextPageToken' , None)

    #Rows
    rowsNew = response.get("reports")[0].get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    rows = rows + rowsNew

    #Recursively query next page
    if pagetoken != None:
        return ga_to_df(analytics,pagetoken,rows)
    else:
        return rows
#====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|
#%%
def main():
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()

    global dfanalytics
    dfanalytics = []

    rows = []
    rows = ga_to_df(analytics,'0', rows)

    dfanalytics = pd.DataFrame(list(rows))
    print("------------------\n",dfanalytics.shape,'\n',dfanalytics.columns,'\n')
    """for ccc in dfanalytics.columns:
    print(ccc,'================\n',dfanalytics[ccc])"""
#====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|
#%%
main()
```

Comment: What are the total rows returning for your report.

Comment: @DaImTo Originally it was pulling 76,973 rows, now with the same date range a day later, it reaches the page limit of 10,000 rows without the code being changed.